# Readtimearray function in Julia TimeSeries package

Tags: csv, time-series, julia

I would like to read a csv file of the following form with readtimearray:

```
"","ES1 Index","VG1 Index","TY1 Comdty","RX1 Comdty","GC1 Comdty"
"1999-01-04",1391.12,3034.53,66.515625,86.2,441.39
"1999-01-05",1404.86,3072.41,66.3125,86.17,440.63
"1999-01-06",1435.12,3156.59,66.4375,86.32,441.7
"1999-01-07",1432.32,3106.08,66.25,86.22,447.67
"1999-01-08",1443.81,3093.46,65.859375,86.36,447.06
"1999-01-11",1427.84,3005.07,65.71875,85.74,449.5
"1999-01-12",1402.33,2968.04,65.953125,86.31,442.92
"1999-01-13",1388.88,2871.23,66.21875,86.52,439.4
"1999-01-14",1366.46,2836.72,66.546875,86.73,440.01
```

However, here's what I get when I evaluate readtimearray("myfile.csv")

```
ERROR: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{UTF8String}, ::Float64)
 in push! at array.jl:460
 in readtimearray at /home/juser/.julia/v0.3/TimeSeries/src/readwrite.jl:25
```

What is it that I am not seeing?

Comment: more details [here](https://github.com/JuliaStats/TimeSeries.jl/blob/fbc1b518dfb56bd8daa09a2e8c0432f478c73f79/src/readwrite.jl)  at `line 6-8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a bug in `readtimearray`.
Empty lines are removed but, to identify them,
the code only looks at the first column.
Since the header has an empty string in the first column, it is removed...

Changing the header of your file to

```
"date","ES1 Index","VG1 Index","TY1 Comdty","RX1 Comdty","GC1 Comdty"
```

addresses the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `convert`, which is meant for use with julia types (see [doc](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/conversion-and-promotion/) for more info).

You parse the string using [Date](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/dates/#constructors):

```
d=Date("1999-04-01","yyyy-mm-dd")
#...
array_of_dates = map(x->Date(x,"yyyy-mm-dd"),array_of_strings)
```